# Blinking Alpha Animation With no fade effect

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a Blink Animation.

This code makes a view to blink fade in and fade out:

```
AlphaAnimation blink = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);

blink.setDuration(500); 
blink.setStartOffset(0); 
//changing it makes more than one animation appear in different time stamps.
blink.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
blink.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
```

I have two issues:

1. setStartOffset(n); --> Changing n makes more than one animation appear in different      time  stamps. Not synced. I want it to be synced, all animations should appear and dissappear at same time.
2. I do not want fade in or fade out, simply visible & gone with few millisecond delay.
   Is there any other Class of Animation that i had to use, or i had to make a custom animation.
   Pls. help.

Comment: If you have a different startOffset at each animation, then of course they will not run synced, as the startOffset is different....why use animation anyway if you don't want to animate anything? You can just set the visibility to visible or invisible/gone with a delay in between...

Comment: See this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html

Comment: I do not want to sleep UI thread that's why i thought an animation would be a better idea.

Comment: Nobody said you should sleep the UI thread and yeah, you shouldn't do it... just toggle the visibility in an interval. I'll create an answer, give me some time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, my answer ... it's a class that toggles visibility of a view in a certain interval. Of course it can be solved differently, maybe you get some inspiration...

```
public static class ViewBlinker {

    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable blinker;

    public ViewBlinker(final View v, final int interval) {
        this.blinker = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                v.setVisibility(v.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE?View.INVISIBLE:View.VISIBLE);
                handler.postDelayed(blinker, interval);
            }
        };
    }

    public void startBlinking() {
        handler.post(blinker);
    }

    public void stopBlinking() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(blinker);
    }

}
```

and you use it like this :

```
    ViewBlinker blinker = new ViewBlinker(YOUR_BLINK_VIEW, YOUR_BLINK_INTERVAL);

    blinker.startBlinking();
```

and when your view is finished blinking, call

```
    blinker.stopBlinking();
```

Answer (score 7):

For animation without the fading you can create your own custom Interpolator:

```
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;

public class StepInterpolator implements Interpolator {

    float mDutyCycle;
    public StepInterpolator(float dutyCycle) {
        mDutyCycle = dutyCycle;
    }

    @Override
    public float getInterpolation(float input) {
        return input < mDutyCycle ? 0 : 1;
    }

}
```

Then set the interpolator in the Animation object:

```
blink.setInterpolator(new StepInterpolator(0.5f));
```

Comment: Thank you... worked like a charm! it would be nice if you explain the code :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, based on cold ash's answer in 2014, all of his/her code can be simplified as below (thanks to lambda):

```
blink.setInterpolator(input -> input < 0.5f ? 0 : 1);
```

Yes, just a single line. Very simple.

Comment: Hi Jasper, welcome to SO. Your answer might work fine but, it would be very nice to add an explanation to your answer so that new developers will understand what exactly you are trying to say with that bunch of code. Thanks